# Statement of Vitali convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f,f_n \in L^p(X,\mu)$, where $p\in[0,\infty)$ and we assume that $\mu(X)<\infty$. From the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem), the statement of Vitali convergence theorem is written as

> $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$ if and only if we have
>
> (i) $f_n$ converges in measure to $f$.
>
> (ii) For every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if a measurable set $E$ satisfies $\mu(E)<\delta$, then for every $n$ we have 
>   $$
> \int_E |f_n|^p d\mu < \varepsilon^p.
> $$
>
> **Remark**: (i) and (ii) implies uniform integrability of $(|f_n|^p)_n$ whereas the uniform integrability of $(|f_n|^p)_n$ implies (ii).

This baffles me because isn't uniform integrability of $(|f_n|^p)_n$ simply equivalent to (ii)? Why do we need (i) at all?

Comment: It seems like you're right. The remark is true though ;)

Comment: That's an interesting way to look at the remark haha. Anyway, perhaps there might be a different definition of uniform integrability that I am not familiar with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uniform integrabilty is not equivalent to ii). Definition of uniform integrabilty is $\int_{|f_n|>M} |f_n| \to 0$ uniformly in $n$ as $M \to \infty$. This is equivalent to ii) plus the condition $\sup_n \int |f_n| <\infty$

Comment: The definition I am familiar with is this "measure theoretic" definition that is found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability#Measure-theoretic_definition . Is the one you are using equivalent to the one that falls under the title "Probability definition" on the same page?

Comment: My definition of UI is the standard definition founf in al standard texts in measure theortic probability (like Chung, Billilgsley, Meyer etc). I think you shouldn't follow the definition in the Wikipedia page. See, for example, Theorem 4.5.3 in Chung.

Comment: I was using the definition in Rudin's book. It could be that the one I am using is outdated, I think I'll take your words for that. Thank you.

Comment: I looked at the definition in Rudin; you have quoted it correctly, but here is my take on this: UI is heavily used in Probability and rarely used outside Probability. Since all Probabilists agree on the definition in Chung's book I would say that you should ignore Rudin's definition.